# How to return string to json format

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = Constants.REQ_MAP_LOGIN, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String vendorloginMethodPost(@RequestBody VendorLogin vendoridlogin) {

    System.out.println(vendoridlogin);
    String message = Constants.EMPTY_STRING;
    String id = dao.getLoginDetails(vendoridlogin);


    if (id == null) {
        message = "login fail";
    } else {
        message = " login Successfully";
    }

    return message;
}
```

How to return response string to json format
how to convert?
In the above, Spring would add "Login sussess or fail " into the response body. 
How can I return a String as a JSON response? I  dont understand that I could add quotes.
Please provide any examples to help explain this concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
    if (id == null) {
        message = "{\"message\":\"login fail\"}";

    } else {
        message = "{\"message\":\"login Successfully\"}";
    }
```

Or if you want response in plain text, you can use :-

```
produces=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE
```

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ResponseBody
public String vendorloginMethodPost(@RequestBody VendorLogin vendoridlogin) {
    ......

    Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
if (id == null) {
     map.put("message","login fail");
     map.put("returnCode",0);
} else {
    map.put("message","login Successfully");
    map.put("returnCode",1);
}
    return map;
}
```

i think this is better

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `Map` as a return type.

```
@RequestMapping(value = Constants.REQ_MAP_LOGIN, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Map<String, String> vendorloginMethodPost(@RequestBody VendorLogin vendoridlogin) {

    // [...]

    if (id == null) {
        return Map.of("message", "login fail");
    } else {
        return Map.of("message", "login success");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can do something like this

```
try {
    if (id == null) {
       message = new JSONObject("login fail").toString();
    } else {
       message = new JSONObject(" login Successfully").toString();
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this as *RestController*, and return an object like below.

```
public class Message(){
    private string message;

    public Message(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage(){
        return this.message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

and you can say

```
return new Message("login success");
```

or

```
return new Message("login failed");
```

It will be clean, you don't have to take care of forming the string on you own and handling escape characters.